# Problems aligning an element at the bottom of a parent element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a `<div>` with a `<h2>` inside it at the bottom of a parent div. The best way to show you is through code so here's the JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/3GGa7/

As you can see, the `project-title` div (and the `<h2>` inside it) is aligned to the top of the `project-header` div. I would like it to sink to the bottom of that div, to look like this:

[image]

However if I apply a `margin-top` to `project-title` it pushes everything down rather than just that div, and if I apply a padding the black background will cover the image.

What's the most elegant way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `.project-title` must be contained within the `.project-header`, give the `.project-header` a `position:relative;` and the `.project-title` a `position:absolute;`

```
.project-header {
    height: 100px;
    position:relative;;
}

.project-title {
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.75;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}
```

Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/gXyEU/

This way, whether you use a bigger image, or change its position or margin, you'll never have to worry about the title, it will always be positioned where it should be.

Answer (score 0):

If your picture size is steady. You can try the css below:

```
.project {
    width: 335px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.project-header {
    height: 100px;
}

.project-title {
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.75;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
        margin-top:25%;
}

.project-title h2 {
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    float:left;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just close your `project-header` div before start of `project-title` div like as

```
<div class="project">
    <div class="project-header" style="background-image:url('http://placekitten.com/200/300');" ></div>
        <div class="project-title">
            <h2>Project title</h2>
        </div>

    <div class="project-description">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ornare felis id enim dignissim dapibus. Maecenas dui mi, ullamcorper eget semper non, varius quis orci. Suspendisse lobortis nibh sed nisi luctus dictum. Sed vel arcu eros. Etiam id varius neque. Cras ac sapien in est fringilla tempor vitae et est.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

FIDDLE is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3GGa7/10/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind setting the `width` of `.project-header`

```
.project-header {
    width: 335px;
    height: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3GGa7/15/)